# sum of the power of fermat point

Tags: geometry

**conjecture：**

> Let $ O, $ $ F_1, $ $ F_2 $ be the circumcenter, [1st Fermat point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FirstFermatPoint.html), [2nd Fermat point](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFermatPoint.html) of $ \triangle ABC, $ respectively. Prove that $$ \text{Power of } F_1 \text{ WRT } \odot (O) \text{ + Power of } F_2 \text{ WRT } \odot (O) \text{ = } -{F_1F_2}^2. $$(the power of WRT see: [Power WRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point))

[image]
I have use GeoGebra test this conjecture are right:see this following [image]

But How to prove this

Comment: FYI: I have an ugly coordinate proof of the conjecture. I'm looking for something more elegant.

Comment: @Blue,It doesn't matter  can you post your proof.Thanks

Comment: @functionsug I've posted a synthetic solution.

Comment: Thanks,I hope can see other methods.such as Blue methods,But Thanks for you solution

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a proof, but I'm unsure if my brain counts as a credible and/or official source :P

Let $\Gamma$ be the circumcircle. Let $G,H,N$ be the centroid, orthocenter and 9-point center. Let $M,X$ be the midpoints of $\overline{HG},\overline{F_1F_2}$. The following facts are well-known:

- $F_1$ and $F_2$ are inverses with respect to the circle $\omega$ on diameter $\overline{HG}$.
- $X$ is the center of the Kiepert hyperbola, and lies on the 9-point circle.

Thus from the first fact $$MG^2=MF_1\cdot MF_2=MX^2-\frac{1}{4}F_1F_2^2\implies\boxed{MX^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(GH^2+F_1F_2^2\right)}.$$ But as $G,H$ are the internal and external similitude centers of $\Gamma$ and the 9-point circle, so $\omega$ is coaxal with these circles. Thus $$\frac{\operatorname{Pow}_{\Gamma}(X)}{\operatorname{Pow}_{\omega}(X)}=\frac{XO^2-R^2}{XM^2-\frac{1}{4}GH^2}=\frac{NO}{NM}=-\frac{NO}{NG}=-3,$$ so $\boxed{XO^2-R^2=-\frac{3}{4}F_1F_2^2}$. By Apollonius' median theorem in $\triangle OF_1F_2$, $$\boxed{XO^2=\frac{1}{2}\left(OF_1^2+OF_2^2\right)-\frac{1}{4}F_1F_2^2},$$ so putting the two together, $$\operatorname{Pow}_{\Gamma}(F_1)+\operatorname{Pow}_{\Gamma}(F_2)=OF_1^2+OF_2^2-2R^2=2XO^2+\frac{1}{2}F_1F_2^2-2R^2=-F_1F_2^2$$

Comment: Thanks The same sa this solution:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c36t316f6h1332333_sum_of_the_power_of_fermat_point

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by OP, the question already has a short ---and quite sophisticated--- answer on [the Art of Problem Solving site, by AoPS user Luis González](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t31171f6h1332333_sum_of_the_power_of_fermat_point). Since OP has requested an alternative approach, I'll outline mine ... which ---fair warning!--- is Tedium incarnate. (I said from the beginning that the proof was "ugly".)

I'll start with the characterization of the [Fermat points](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPoints.html) as points of concurrency of lines associated with the two [Napoleon Triangle-related configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon's_theorem):

> Given $\triangle ABC$, erect "outer" equilateral triangles $\triangle D_{+}BC$, $\triangle E_{+}CA$, $\triangle F_{+}AB$ that do not overlap $\triangle ABC$; and erect "inner" equilateral triangles $\triangle D_{-}BC$, $\triangle E_{-}CA$, $\triangle F_{-}AB$ that do overlap $\triangle ABC$. Then $\overleftrightarrow{AD_{+}}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BE_{+}}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CF_{+}}$ concur at the first Fermat point (here, $K_{+}$), while $\overleftrightarrow{AD_{-}}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BE_{-}}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CF_{-}}$ concur at the second Fermat point ($K_{-}$).

Coordinatizing, with the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$ at the origin ($O$), we can take
$$A = r(1,0) \qquad B = r(\cos 2C, \sin 2C) \qquad C = r ( \cos 2B, - \sin 2B) $$
where $r$ is the circumradius. Note that, for instance, $O$, $E_{+}$, $E_{-}$ are collinear with the midpoint, $M$, of $\overline{AC}$; in particular, the reader can verify that
$$E_{\pm} = \frac{\cos B \pm \sqrt{3} \sin B}{\cos B} \;M = 2 r \cos\left(B\mp \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\;(\cos B, -\sin B)$$
Likewise,
$$F_{\pm} = 2 r \cos\left(C\mp \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\;(\cos C, \sin C)$$

From here, one can exploit a computer algebra system to determine equations for lines $\overleftrightarrow{BE_{\pm}}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{CF_{\pm}}$, and to generate coordinates of their intersections (the Fermat points, $K_{\pm}$). With a bit of fiddling, one can express the coordinates in this symmetric form:

$$K_{\pm} = \frac{
\left(\quad\begin{align}
A \; \sin B \; ( 4 \sin B \sin C \pm \sqrt{3} \sin A ) \\
+ \; B \; \sin B \; ( 4 \sin C \sin A \pm \sqrt{3} \sin B ) \\
+ \; C \; \sin C \; ( 4 \sin A \sin B \pm \sqrt{3} \sin C )
\end{align}
\quad\right)
}{ 6 \sin A \sin B \sin C \pm \sqrt{3} ( \sin^2A + \sin^2 B + \sin^2C ) } \tag{1}$$

Alternatively, with $a = |\overline{BC}|$, etc, we have a somewhat-more-compact representation:
$$K_{\pm} = \frac{ 2 a b c ( A + B + C ) \pm r \sqrt{3} \left(  a^2 A + b^2 B + c^2 C \right)}{
3 a b c \pm r \sqrt{3} \left(\;a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \right)} \tag{2}$$

We could even write
$$K_{\pm} = \pm \;\frac{
A ( 2 T \pm T_a )
+ B ( 2 T \pm T_b )
+ C ( 2 T \pm T_c )
}{6 T_{\pm}} \tag{3}$$
where $T := |\triangle ABC|$, and $T_a$, $T_b$, $T_c$ are the areas of the equilateral triangles, and $T_{\pm}$ is [the area of the corresponding inner-or-outer Napoleon Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon's_theorem#Areas_and_sides_of_inner_and_outer_Napoleon_triangles). (Note: $T = T_{+} - T_{-}$.)

I'll also note that
$$\begin{align}
&6 \sin A \sin B \sin C \pm \sqrt{3} \left( \sin^2A + \sin^2B + \sin^2C \right) \\
=\;&2 \sqrt{3} \left(\;\sin A \sin\left(A \pm \frac{\pi}{3}\right) + \sin B \sin\left(B \pm \frac{\pi}{3}\right) + \sin C \sin\left(C \pm \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\;\right)
\end{align} \tag{4}$$
which makes me think that the numerator has a clever form involving $\pm \frac{\pi}{3}$, although I never found anything completely satisfying.

I've been stalling, because the remainder of this "proof" of the relation

$$\operatorname{pow}(K_{+}) + \operatorname{pow}(K_{-}) = -|\overline{K_{+}K_{-}}|^2 \tag{$\star$}$$

amounts to letting the computer algebra system verify this equivalent form (leveraging the fact that the center of the circle in question lies at the origin):
$$|K_{+}|^2 + |K_{-}|^2 - (K_{+}\cdot K_{-}) - r^2 = 0 \tag{$\star\star$}$$
where we invoke the relations
$$|A|^2 = |B|^2 = |C|^2 = r^2, \quad B\cdot C = r^2 \cos 2A, \quad C\cdot A = r^2 \cos 2B, \quad A\cdot B = r^2 \cos 2C$$
$$A + B + C = \pi$$

... making for an anti-climactic, and wholly-unsatisfying, QED. $\square$

---

The reason I have so many alternative representations of $K_{\pm}$ is that I was looking for a form that makes relation $(\star\star)$ "obvious", or something that would provide a helpful larger context under which $(\star)$ holds. I have failed in these quests so far. Unless and until profound inspiration strikes, the above is all I have to offer.